# Caffe2: make ops fails when installing densepose

Tags: caffe2

I am trying to install [DensePose](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DensePose) but run into problems when executing `make ops`.

First I get error `Caffe2Config.cmake` not found, but after following the instructions here [Caffe2 build from source](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu&configuration=compile) the `Caffe2Config.cmake` ends up under the `build` directory.

Adding the path to the `build` folder gives then the following error:

```
  CMake Error at /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/Caffe2Config.cmake:14 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/public/utils.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/Caffe2Config.cmake:17 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/public/threads.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/Caffe2Config.cmake:88 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/build/public/cuda.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

The paths are clearly wrong since the requested `cmake-`files are under `pytorch/cmake/public` instead of `pytorch/build/public`.

How can one resolve that? I have just followed the instructions and the tests one makes along the way works. It seems to be the installation of `Caffe2` that causes the problem?

Comment: Did you solve it? I met a similar problem when executing "make ops".

Comment: I think I came to the conclusion that I had the wrong version of Cuda and Ubuntu. I will try docker instead

Comment: I modified the variable Caffe2_DIR in densepose/CmakeLists.txt from .../pytorch/build to .../pytorch/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2 and the problem was solved. However, other issues arose...

Comment: @BetterEnglish I couldn't remember whether it was me who added its definition. If there isn't a definition of Caffe2_DIR, you can define it yourself like `set(Caffe2_DIR "/path/to/pytorch/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/")`.

Comment: @BetterEnglish Are there any more error messages? I don't think you should set cuDNN dirs to where DensePose is, though. They should be pointing to the directory of cuDNN at least.

Comment: @HarperLong did you succeed to run the densepose project ?

Comment: @HarperLong Here is my issue on github  ` https://github.com/facebookresearch/DensePose/issues/150`

Comment: @BetterEnglish Yes of course. It was a long story though.

Comment: @HarperLong, did you tell me how did you install Caffe2. I installed it using this link  `https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu` but it seems missing many folders and files like `pytorch/c10` I copied it manually !! and still missing some other files

Comment: @HarperLong, I passed the make ops but I fail the test with `undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal10LogMessagelsEPKc` error. I have one protobuf installation with conda.

Comment: @BetterEnglish Great, there's only one step to success! It's a protobuf version issue. Since you build Caffe2 from source, you can use the protobuf build in the Caffe2 directory. Refer here: http://linkinpark213.com/2018/11/18/densepose-minesweeping/#2-7-Undefined-symbol-ZN6google8protobuf8internal9ArenaImpl28AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanupEmPFvPvE

Comment: @HarperLong, I already use it but still having the same error. I installed Caffe2 using anaconda and I also installed protobuf using anaconda. I read in other Github that we can run the inference script without succeed this test. but still having this https://github.com/facebookresearch/DensePose/issues/33

Comment: @HarperLong, I finished by running the code !!!

Comment: @BetterEnglish Congratulations! Could you please share how you solved the issues?

Comment: @Harper, My problem is coming from the installation of Caffe2. At the beginning, I used the anaconda version which does not contain detectron. I build seprately caffe2 and detectron which does not work. Now, I installed the binary version with cuda-9.2 on ubuntu 18.04 which works correctly

Comment: @BetterEnglish Thanks for your kindly sharing!

Comment: @HarperLong, I write a script for webcam demo but the frame rate is very low. I used 1080 GTX as in the original paper but getting 6 fps. However, in the paper they said 20-26 fps!!! What about you ? I think because of this error  https://github.com/facebookresearch/DensePose/issues/80#issuecomment-442130539

Comment: @BetterEnglish Me too, and I don't even have that warning at all. I even disabled its I/O part and made sure that the model is pre-loaded.

Comment: @HarperLong, Do you mean that you have 6 fps without any warnings?

Comment: @BetterEnglish Yes, and it was a bit lower than 6fps, about 5.5 fps, to be honest. I'm using a GTX1080Ti.

Comment: @HarperLong, Really!!! :)

Comment: @HarperLong, Are you at NIPS?

Comment: @BetterEnglish Nope. I'm just a M1 freshman student yet. Were you there?

Comment: @HarperLong, Yes! It is a huge conference!

Comment: @BetterEnglish Congrats! I wish I could attend it next year.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the environment variable `Caffe2_DIR` to the directory of the missing files solved the problem.

As you mentioned, these files are in the `pytorch/cmake/public` directory instead of `pytorch/build/public`. To define the path of Caffe2 manually, open the `CMakeLists.txt` in the densepose folder, add one line in the beginning:

```
set(Caffe2_DIR "/home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/cmake/")
```

Run `make ops` again and the issue should be solved. If not, also try

```
set(Caffe2_DIR "/home/erikbylow/Code/LocalLibs/pytorch/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/")
```

Also, after DensePose is successfully installed, remember to append its path to PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/densepose/
```